# How to add a texture in jmonkey

Tags: jmonkeyengine

Hello I have a pretty simple question, I'm new to jmonkey and I want to add a .jpg file to the /assets/textures folder and dragging and dropping the file doesn't appear to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the jpg file into the textures folder in finder works. For some reason it won't allow me to do it using the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy it from Finder and then paste it into the SDK.